# RegEx pattern in glob function

Tags: php, regex, filenames, glob

I recive a filename in a function. I want to return all files similar to this file (by filename) from other directory. I wrote this:

```
    $thumbDir = $this->files_path.'thumbs/';
    $toglob = $thumbDir.pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_FILENAME ).'_[0-9]+\x[0-9]+_thb.'.pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    foreach (glob($toglob) as $key => $value) {
        echo $value;
    }
```

But it doesn't work. I search files which their filename is:

```
oldFileName_[one or more digits]x[one or more digits]_thb.oldFileNameExtension
```

I will be very grateful if someone help me with this :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[`glob()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) is really a quasi-regex engine.  From a comment on the docs, it allows a `?` and a `*`:

> glob uses two special symbols that act like sort of a blend between a meta-character and a quantifier.  These two characters are the * and ?
>
> The ? matches 1 of any character except a /
>
> The * matches 0 or more of any character except a /
>
> If it helps, think of the * as the pcre equivalent of .* and ? as the pcre equivalent of the dot (.)

This means you can't use your expression `_[0-9]+\x[0-9]+_thb.` in `glob()`.  Instead, you can look in the whole directory and see if it matches with [`preg_match()`](https://www.php.net/preg_match):

```
$glob = glob('/path/to/dir/*');
foreach($glob as $file) {
    if(preg_match('/_\d+x\d+_thb\./', $file)) {
        // Valid match
        echo $file;
    }
}
```

Realize that in `glob(/path/to/dir/*);`, the `*` does not match a `/` so this will not get any files in subdirectories.  It will only loop through every file and directory in that path; if you want to go deeper, you will have to make a recursive function.

Note I cleaned your [expression](http://regex101.com/r/cU9eV4):

```
_\d+x\d+_thb\.
```

`\d` roughly equals `[0-9]` (it also includes Arabic digit characters, etc.), you do not need to escape `x` (so no `\x`), and you want to escape the period (`\.`).

Comment: hey that's my glob comment you quoted from, my day is made, hoozah! :)

Comment: @CrayonViolent haha awesome, it was one of the better PHP doc comments I've seen -- had a good number of upvotes too.  You must be a `glob()` person if you stumbled across this question ;)