# negative pattern matching to exclude certain files using glob

Tags: php, glob

I am using glob to get all images from a directory. However, some of the images in the directory are thumbnails which are identified by a "-m" immediately before the file extension and I want to exclude these from the file list. So, for example there could be:

```
image-1.png
image-1-m.png 
portrait.png 
portrait-m.png 
front-panel-cold.png
front-panel-cold-m.png 
front-panel-warm.png 
front-panel-warm-m.png
```

Using

```
foreach(glob($imdir."/*[!m].*") as $img) {
    echo $img . "<br>\n";
}
```

I can list all the files which don't end with m, however that also excludes front-panel-warm.png. I can't find a way of escaping the hyphen:

```
glob($imdir."/*[!\-m].*")
```

gives no results,

```
glob($imdir."/*[!-m].*")
```

gives the same results as     [!m] and

```
glob($imdir."/*[!--m].*")
```

excludes all files ending with any letter before n. I've also tried using a brace

```
glob($imdir."/*[!{-m}].*", GLOB_BRACE)
```

but that doesn't seem to work either.

Any ideas where I am going wrong, or is this simply something I need to use preg_match for?

Comment: use double backslash for escaping hyphen `[!\\-m]`

Comment: Seems rather counterintuitive, @tzafar, and just like [!\-m] it returns no results at all.

Comment: i have checked this and its working fine `glob($imdir."/*[!-m].*")`

Comment: Does it show files ending in "m" but not "-m"? It's not working that way for me.

Answer (score 3):

Use this to exclude all files ending with `-m`

```
foreach(glob($imdir."/*[!-]?[!m]?.png") as $img) {
    echo $img . "<br>\n";
}
```

Comment: I cant get your suggestion to work @tsafar. It just gives a list of all files except two: one because it contains no hyphen and one because it conrtains -1-m. I've done a test page if it helps clarify the issue: [link](http://b-known.net/globtest.php).

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, As per the directory content you provided, I have created Two Type of Regex using [glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function, In glob function i have search alot for using two type of condition but didnt got any usefull information, so i have write it in my own way.
Also Read about glob in stackoverflow answer : [**`Link`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23566103/regex-pattern-in-glob-function)

**First :** Create an empty array then Loop through the directory using regex `/*[!-m].*` which doesnot match any files which has `-m` in the filename and put it in created array which **$arr**.

**Second**: Again Loop through the directory in first **`foreach`** and check for if not **`in_array`** and add it.

```
image-1.png
image-1-m.png 
portrait.png 
portrait-m.png 
front-panel-cold.png
front-panel-cold-m.png 
front-panel-warm.png 
front-panel-warm-m.png

$imdir = 'img';

$arr = [];
foreach(glob($imdir."/*[!-m].*") as $img) {
    $arr[] = $img;
    foreach(glob($imdir."/*[!-]?.*") as $img1) {
        if(!in_array($img1,$arr)) {
            $arr[] = $img1;
        }
    }
}

echo '<pre>';print_r($arr);echo '</pre>';
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => img/front-panel-cold.jpg
    [1] => img/front-panel-warm.jpg
    [2] => img/portrait.jpg
    [3] => img/image-1.jpg
    [4] => img/portrait.jpg
)

$r = array_unique($arr);

echo '<pre>';print_r($r);echo '</pre>';
```

**Resultant output as you required:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => img/front-panel-cold.jpg
    [1] => img/front-panel-warm.jpg
    [2] => img/portrait.jpg
    [3] => img/image-1.jpg
)


echo " ---------------- ";
echo "</br>";


foreach(glob($imdir."/??*[!-m].*") as $img) {
    echo $img . "<br>\n";
}

**Output:**
img/front-panel-cold.jpg
img/image-1.jpg
img/portrait.jpg

echo " ---------------- ";
echo "</br>";

foreach(glob($imdir."/*[!-]?.*") as $img) {
    echo $img . "<br>\n";
}

**Output:**
img/front-panel-cold.jpg
img/front-panel-warm.jpg
img/portrait.jpg
```